# Can we enable/disable airplane mode using robotium in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, robotium

I need to disable network in the android emulator to test error messages , is there any way we can do it using robotium ?

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681695/can-wifi-be-switched-on-off-in-test-case-through-robotium/13780569#

and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/android-how-to-enable-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2#

Answer (score -1):

You can use **ExtSolo** library http://docs.testdroid.com/_static/extSolodocs/com/bitbar/recorder/extensions/ExtSolo.html
it is an extension of Solo library. 
(You can download from http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html)

Have a look at the keyword **turnWifi(boolean enabled),** it is what you are looking for.